# SpringBoot with Tomcat uses around 190mb of memory. What processes are running within Springboot?

Tags: java, tomcat, docker, spring-boot

I am running an application with Springboot which has an embedded Tomcat inside a docker container. I have given my max heap size to be 64mb. However, I see the total memory consumption is around 190mb.

If I try to start the container with memory limit of 128mb the container fails to start. What other processes will run along with tomcat and app? How to know which process is consuming the memory?

Comment: It should be using just one process. Would be good to provide a thread dump. Also I would recommend attach a profiler e.g. https://visualvm.java.net/ and see how many classes are loaded, what is consuming the memory etc.

Comment: @Aditya Note that max heap size only limits the heap memory, and the jvm will use more memory than those 64MB (see https://plumbr.eu/blog/memory-leaks/why-does-my-java-process-consume-more-memory-than-xmx). How many more? It depends. Also you can try to login inside the container and use top or similar to make sure only tomcat is running inside the container